# Set cursor position in Mac OS

Tags: cocoa, macos, cursor-position

I want to write a little vnc similar program that moves the Mac OS cursor to a position (x, y) given through a protocol which gets data from Bonjour service. The problem is that I don't know how to move the cursor!

I'm working with Cocoa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can be forgiven for not looking in Quartz Display Services for this one. The function you're after is [`CGWarpMouseCursorPosition`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWarpMouseCursorPosition).

Since the documentation doesn't say, you'll have to experiment to determine which co-ordinate system it uses—i.e., where the origin is and which way positive y goes.