# Python: How to click on the screen at a specific place in python, MAC OS

Tags: python, macos

I want to use a python program to move the cursor around on the screen and click on a specific location in Mac OS.

I have seen some good threads on this for Windows and Ubuntu, but I'm looking for OSX.

Windows:
[Using Perl, Python, or Ruby, how to write a program to "click" on the screen at scheduled time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007391/using-perl-python-or-ruby-how-to-write-a-program-to-click-on-the-screen-at)

Ubuntu:
[How to click on a coordinate on a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672286/how-to-click-on-a-coordinate-on-a-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching for "how to move the cursor in OSX using Python", you'll find much better results if you search for "how to move the cursor in OSX", then search for how to use that interface with Python.

It seems that [Objective-C/Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570584/set-cursor-position-in-mac-os) is used to integrate with the native Mac OS X interface, and the Python documentation recommends using [PyObjC as a Python binding to Apple’s Objective-C/Cocoa framework](http://docs.python.org/py3k/using/mac.html#gui-programming-on-the-mac).

Hopefully this is enough information to get you on your way.